# Two-way repeated measure ANOVA with non-normal residuals

Tags: normal-distribution, mixed-model, anova

I have sampled data and the residuals *should* be normally distributed, however due to the presence of a couple outliers the residuals are not normally distributed (Kologorov-Smirnov and Shapiro-Wilk < 0.001). The qqplots and residual histograms are “close” to being normal (if you’re being generous).

My questions are: (1) How important is the assumption of normality to a two-way repeated measure ANOVA if the underlying residuals are not normally distributed? (2) Would it still be correct to fit such “non-normal" data to a two-way repeated measure ANOVA given the violation of normality? And, if it is not correct, then (3) are there any other treatments I could do to my data or robust non-parametric alternatives? Could I just repeat the analysis without outliers?

I was also thinking of using a LMEM but I’m not sure of the appropriateness of that model, either, given that the residuals are not normally distributed.

Side note: I’m using R syntax for this analysis.